# Django : How do you check if an user has the rights on a pk value inserted in the URL - decorator

Tags: django, url, permissions, decorator, group

I am a newbee in django. In my website, when the user logs in, he is redirected to a page with a dropdown menu where he has to choose a contract on which he wants to work. After selecting the contract he is redirected to the specific homepage define with a ID in the url. The ID value comes from the ID of the contract in the database.

What
How can I check by a function or a decorator that the user has the rights to be on this contract. Because any user could right the numbers in the url and access to a page where he should not have access. By example, an user has the right to the contracts 109 and 144, so he can go on the urls "home/109" and "home/144", but if is change the value in the url to another one, he should not have access

Here is my view of the dropdown menu :

```
@authenticated_user
def selectcontrat(request) :

    context = initialize_context(request)
    form_client = SelectClient(request.POST, user=request.user)
    if form_client.is_valid():
        id_contrat = request.POST.get("ID_Customer")
    
        return redirect(reverse('home', args=(id_contrat,)))

    context['form_client'] = form_client

    return render(request, 'base/selectcontrat.html', context)
```

Here the views of the home page :

```
@authenticated_user
def home(request, id_contrat=None):
    context = initialize_context(request)

    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

The urls :

from django.urls import path
from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/<int:id_contrat>/', views.home, name="home"),
    path('', views.loginAD, name="login"),
    path('signin', views.sign_in, name='signin'),
    path('callback', views.callback, name='callback'),
    path('selectcontrat', views.selectcontrat, name='selectcontrat')
```

The model is the relation between a user and a group. which group the user has righs.

```
class Groups(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    IDCustomer = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    GroupName = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    CreatedOn = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.


class AADJNTGroup(models.Model):

    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ID_User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ID_Group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CreatedOn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    CreatedBy = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

To do that, I tried to do a decorator, but I do not know how to get the id_contrac value that is redirected after the form. How can I get this value in a decorator, like that then I could check the rights on the database.

The decorator not working :

```
def check_pk(view_func) :

    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):

        list_user_rights = AADJNTGroup.objects.filter(ID_group_id=args[0]).values_list('ID_User_id', flat=True)
        print(list_user_rights)

    return wrapper_func
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Do you mean how can i stop a `user` to not see things of another user,as far as  I am able to understand, because the `url` for `home` route shows that if any authenticated user gives I'd of another user in route, so it can see his details.

Comment: Hi @Sunderam, sorry for my English ! Maybe it is not clear so I repeat. What I mean is that some user have the rights to different content (different clients). The home page is a generic page but with the pk value, it is the specific home page for a client. After the authentification, any user could right in the url “/home/12” and would have access to this client but may be he has not the rights. I want to control that. To forbid users to go on pages that they should not have access

Comment: The temporary solution is you can match that particular `pk`, with current user `pk` through `request.user` and place if condition like `if pk_variable!=current_user_id_variable`, then return any template which will show the page of not found or simply return `HttpResponse("<h1> page not found</H1>")` which will show this type of message.Well, it's not much better way but you can do that.

Comment: thanks @SunderamDubey I want to do that in a decorator. I tried to do it, but I do not know how to get the id_value that is redirected after the form in a decorator. Can you help me please.

Comment: `request.user` give the current user `object` not the `id` or `pk` of current login user, if you want `id`, then you can simply get by `request.user.id` and you will get it, but then if you run any condition, so make sure that you compare both the `id's`, if any single item is `object`, so you cannot compare or run any condition for object with id, as i stated in my last comment, if you seriously look at it, you'll notice there both the variables are `pk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a decorator, that requests the different database to check the rights

##### Here is the decorator

```
def check_user_rights():
    def wrapper_func(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func)
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
           
            # THE ID THAT I CAN COLLECT
            ID_contrat = kwargs["id_contrat"]
            User_ID = request.user.id
            
            # THE SQL REQUEST TO GET THE VALUE
            list_user_rights = AADJNTGroup.objects.filter(ID_User_id=User_ID).values_list('ID_Group_id', flat=True)
            ID_contrat_list = list(list_user_rights)
            Contrat_right = Groups.objects.all().filter(ID__in=ID_contrat_list).values_list('IDCustomer', flat=True)
            
            # Compare the rights
            if ID_contrat in Contrat_right :
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)  

            else :
                return HttpResponse("<h1> page not found</H1>")
            
        return wrapper
    return wrapper_func
```

Answer (score 0):

If using class based views you can use [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin)

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class MyView(UserPassesTestMixin, View):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.email.endswith('@example.com')
```

if using function views you can use the [user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def email_check(user):
    return user.email.endswith('@example.com')

@user_passes_test(email_check)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: thank you for your help ! I try to do it in a decorator by getting directly the id of the form, that is in the url However I do not know how to get it in a decorator. Can you help me please. I tried something but that does not work

Comment: The decorator will only pass the user, it might be easier to switch to a class based view and use `UserPassesTestMixin` as the test_func will have access to `self`, from there you can get `self.request.user` or `self.request.POST` or any other information you need.